# Remove controller directive in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

js

```
.directive("navigation", function(RecursionHelper){
    return{
        //restrict = "E",
        scope:{
            menu : '='
        },
        template :
                '<ul class="" role="menu" ng-repeat="value in menu" ng-class="{\'nav navbar-nav\': value.firstlvl==\'true\' , \'dropdown-menu\': value.firstlvl==\'false\'} ">'+
                    '<li class=""  ng-class="{\'dropdown-submenu\': value != undefined} " >'+ 
                            '<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">'+
                                ' {{value.vcCategoryDescription}}'+
                                '<navigation menu="value.SUB"></navigation>'+
                            '</a>'+
                        // '<ul class="sub dropdown-menu" role="menu" >'+
                            // '<li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="value in menu>'+
                                // '<a data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0" >{{value.SUB}}</a>'+

                            // '</li>'
                        // '</ul>'
                    '</li>'+
                '</ul>',

         compile: function(element) {
            return RecursionHelper.compile(element, function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn){
                // Define your normal link function here.
                // Alternative: instead of passing a function,
                // you can also pass an object with 
                // a 'pre'- and 'post'-link function.
            });
        }
    }
});
```

html

```
<div  class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-12 bs-menu">
                             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                                    <navigation menu="category"></navigation>
</div>
```

For now I'm want to remove this part `<navigation menu="category"></navigation>`. Because this `<navigation>` for dropdown submenu cannot working. When looping, `<ul><navigation><li></li></navigation></ul>`, this to effect my dropdown submenu can probaly function. Can anybody have idea or solution?

Comment: You can hide the navigation, adding the attributte: `ng-hide="myVar"`, or remove from DOM with `ng-if="myVar"`.

Comment: You means is in the html function to ass ng-hide and ng-if?

Comment: `<navigation ng-hide="..." menu="category">` for example.

Comment: I am try already but still have show it..

Answer (score 0):

Within your directive definition object set replace: true